# 2 methods to parse the same pattern of line in a file

Tags: java

I use 2 methods in order to parse those 2 lines:

```
flux=rp_evtmedprev_out
partitions=a054010a,a054020a,a054030a,a034040a,a054050a,a054060a,a054070a,a054080a,a054090a
```

This is the call:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        httpConn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;

String flux = reader.readLine();
String partitionsString = reader.readLine();
insertToplogieNatures(flux, topologie);
insertToplogiePartitions(partitionsString, topologie);
```

Is there a way to merge those 2 methods:

```
public void insertToplogiePartitions(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    String[] splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = line.split("=");
    splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = splitLigneDeuxiemePartie[1].split(",");
    Partition partTemp;
    List<Partition> partitionsBuild = new ArrayList<Partition>();

    for (String partStringTemp : splitLigneDeuxiemePartie) {
        partTemp = new Partition();
        partTemp.setHostname(partStringTemp);
        partitionsBuild.add(partTemp);
    }
    topologie.setPartitions(partitionsBuild);
}

public void insertToplogieNatures(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    String[] splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = line.split("=");
    splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = splitLigneDeuxiemePartie[1].split(",");

    List<String> naturesBuild = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String natureTemp : splitLigneDeuxiemePartie) {
        naturesBuild.add(natureTemp);
    }
    topologie.setNatures(naturesBuild);
}
```

If it's possible, I'm not even sure that it would be a good idea due to readability.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Keep in mind that cutting out extra indentation is fine, but cutting out newlines is not!

Comment: @Pimgd: Sorry. I didn't intend to remove that line break and I didn't spot my mistake either.

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: @h.j.k. : Yes indeed I am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part could be merged, for sure.

```
public void insertToplogiePartitions(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    String[] splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = line.split("=");
    splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = splitLigneDeuxiemePartie[1].split(",");
```

Wrap it in a method

```
public String[] extractSplitLigneDeuxiemePartieFromLine(String line){
    String[] splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = line.split("=");
    return splitLigneDeuxiemePartie[1].split(",");
}
```

and use it like so:

```
public void insertToplogiePartitions(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    String[] splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = extractSplitLigneDeuxiemePartieFromLine(line);
    Partition partTemp;
    List<Partition> partitionsBuild = new ArrayList<Partition>();

    for (String partStringTemp : splitLigneDeuxiemePartie) {
        partTemp = new Partition();
        partTemp.setHostname(partStringTemp);
        partitionsBuild.add(partTemp);
    }
    topologie.setPartitions(partitionsBuild);
}

public void insertToplogieNatures(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    String[] splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = extractSplitLigneDeuxiemePartieFromLine(line);
    List<String> naturesBuild = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String natureTemp : splitLigneDeuxiemePartie) {
        naturesBuild.add(natureTemp);
    }
    topologie.setNatures(naturesBuild);
}
```

For the rest, it's better to take a separate approach because these functions do different things.

Try [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) for the natures.

```
public void insertToplogieNatures(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    topologie.setNatures(
        Arrays.asList(extractSplitLigneDeuxiemePartieFromLine(line))
    );
}
```

For the partitions, you could perhaps simplify by making a new constructor for `Partition` that takes `hostName` as parameter:

```
public void insertToplogiePartitions(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    String[] splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = extractSplitLigneDeuxiemePartieFromLine(line);
    Partition partTemp;
    List<Partition> partitionsBuild = new ArrayList<Partition>();

    for (String partStringTemp : splitLigneDeuxiemePartie) {
        partTemp = new Partition(partStringTemp);
        partitionsBuild.add(partTemp);
    }
    topologie.setPartitions(partitionsBuild);
}
```

Allowing you to remove storing to temporary local variable:

```
public void insertToplogiePartitions(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    String[] splitLigneDeuxiemePartie = extractSplitLigneDeuxiemePartieFromLine(line);

    List<Partition> partitionsBuild = new ArrayList<Partition>();
    for (String partStringTemp : splitLigneDeuxiemePartie) {
        partitionsBuild.add(new Partition(partStringTemp));
    }
    topologie.setPartitions(partitionsBuild);
}
```

But now that you have only a single use of `splitLigneDeuxiemePartie`, you don't need to store that in a local variable either:

```
public void insertToplogiePartitions(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    List<Partition> partitionsBuild = new ArrayList<Partition>();
    for (String partStringTemp : extractSplitLigneDeuxiemePartieFromLine(line)) {
        partitionsBuild.add(new Partition(partStringTemp));
    }
    topologie.setPartitions(partitionsBuild);
}
```

Sometimes local stores help with clarification, and sometimes they don't. In this case, you have french variable names which I don't understand, and the local variable names don't help me understand your code, so I prefer the shortened form.

...

Although, if we're going to use a constructor which takes a `hostName`, you might as well label your temporary variable as such.

```
public void insertToplogiePartitions(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    List<Partition> partitionsBuild = new ArrayList<Partition>();
    for (String hostName : extractSplitLigneDeuxiemePartieFromLine(line)) {
        partitionsBuild.add(new Partition(hostName));
    }
    topologie.setPartitions(partitionsBuild);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `try-with-resource`

You should use `try-with-resource` on your `BufferedReader` for safe and efficient handling of the underlying I/O resource:

```
try (InputReader source = new InputReader(httpConn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(source)) {
    String flux = reader.readLine();
    String partitionsString = reader.readLine();
    insertToplogieNatures(flux, topologie);
    insertToplogiePartitions(partitionsString, topologie);
} catch (IOException e /* something more specific if possible */) {
    // handle exception
}
```

#### Java 8 stream processing

A [`Function<String, T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) can be your friend here, as you recognize you are doing something similar in both:

1. Strip out the 'key'.
2. Split values by `","` into tokens.
3. Optionally converting resulting tokens to `Partition` objects for `partitionsString`, and leaving them as they are for `flux` (this is where `Function<String, T>` comes into play).
4. Put resulting objects into a `List`.

You can have a helper method that does these steps for you:

```
private static final Pattern SPLITTER = Pattern.compile(",");

private static <T> toList(String line, Function<String, T> mapper) {
    return SPLITTER.splitAsStream(line.substring(1 + line.indexOf('=')))
                    .map(mapper)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here, we use [`Pattern.splitAsStream(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) to create our `Stream<String>` of tokens, [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) each of them to our desired type before collecting them [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

Both your methods can then be refactored as such:

```
public void insertToplogiePartitions(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    topologie.setPartitions(toList(line, Partition::of));
}

public void insertToplogieNatures(String line, Topologie topologie) {
    topologie.setNatures(toList(line, Function.identity()));
}
```

This assumes that you have a `static` `Partition.of(String)` method such that it can be used as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) here.

```
public class Partition {

    // ...

    public static Partition of(String name) {
        Partition result = new Partition();
        result.setHostname(name);
        return result;
    }

}
```